# How can I fix an Inset plot to the top right corner of the main plot?

Tags: plotting, inset

I want to export multiple plots and always have a small picture of another plot in the top right corner (as there is no data of the main plot in this region). However, it would be nice if I didn't have to set the position argument in Inset[] manually, as my y-values change for every plot.
Thank you for any help! Below is an example of my code with the export part cut out off the For-loop.
The issue is in the last line of the code, where I try to determine the position of the Inset-plot depending on the y-values, which is not working very well.

```
For[zz = 1, zz <= 4, zz++,
 LargeRangePlotLargeM = 
  ListPlot[{ DeltaDeltaPPS2to5LargeM[[zz]],  
    DeltaDeltaRS2to5LargeM[[zz]], DeltaDeltaPRS2to5LargeM[[zz]], 
    DeltaDeltaGHZ2to5LargeM[[zz]]}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", 
   PlotRange -> All];
 LargeRangePlotWithLargeM = 
  ListPlot[{DeltaDeltaPPS2to5[[zz]], DeltaDeltaRS2to5[[zz]], 
    DeltaDeltaPRS2to5[[zz]], DeltaDeltaGHZ2to5[[zz]]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"PPS", "RS", "PRS",  "GHZ"},  
   AxesLabel -> {"M", "FSA"}, 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["N = ``", zz + 1], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers",  PlotRange -> All, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[LargeRangePlotLargeM, {750, 
      2 * DeltaDeltaGHZ2to5[[1]][[2]][[2]]}]];
]
```

Simpler code with the same question might look like this:

```
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}];
pcombined = 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Epilog -> Inset[p2, {5, 0.5}]]
```

How do I now define the position argument inside Inset in a way that it moves the plot to the top right corner without having to choose plot specific values manually?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add code for different  (small) sample plots to clarify what you want to achieve? Adding code is usually extremely helpful for formulating answers.

Comment: Yes, of course:

Comment: You can use Scaled in spacifying the inset plot's co-ordinates. For example compare: Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Cos[x], {x, -1, 1}], Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 3}}] and Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Cos[x], {x, -1, 1}], Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-1, 3}}]

Comment: Doesn't this still require knowledge of my data, because I choose the PlotRange manually? If I do not know what y-values to expect, how do I transfer this?

Comment: Maybe `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[p2, {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}], ImageSize -> Large]` ?

Comment: This almost works. However, it moves the plot so far to the top right that it I can only see the bottom left quarter of the Inset-plot. It appears that the middle of the plot is at the top right corner of the main plot and everything outside is cut off.

Comment: @camileri I get that the {Right, Top} (3rd argument) corner of the inset is placed at the {Right, Top} (2nd argument) corner of the main plot so the inset is fully visible.

Comment: Oh yes!
I missed that you added a third argument to the Inset! This works perfectly in the example and I hope that it will work for all of my other plots as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: While this works perfectly for the Plot[Sin[x]] - example, it still cuts off the very top right off the plot for my ListPlots. The last data point is not shown and the y axis-labels are sometimes cut off at the top. I don't know how to upload the screenshot I've made to make this more clear though.
If you happen to know a way to just move it very slightly towards the bottom left, that would be great!

Comment: @camileri Please try adjusting the `PlotRange` of the inset or adding some `Padding`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled) and [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled) as position specifications. Since you want the full graphic including image padding included in the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset), use `ImageScaled[{1,1}]` for the alignment point, and use `Scaled[{1,1}]` for the position so that the frame ticks show up at the top and right of the inset graphic. For example, here's a graphic with frame ticks:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Frame->True, FrameTicks->All]
```

[image]

And here is how to inset the graphic using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog):

```
Plot[
    Sin[x],
    {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    Epilog -> Inset[p, Scaled[{1,1}], ImageScaled[{1,1}]],
    ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use four of the five possible arguments of `Inset` to position and scale the auxiliary plot. Like so:

```
aux = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π},
  Epilog -> Inset[aux, {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}, Scaled[{.4, .4}]]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Notes

- The 1st argument is, of course, the auxiliary plot.
- The 2nd argument tells `Plot` to put the auxiliary plot in the top-right corner of the main plot.
- The 3nd argument tells `Plot` to align the top-right corner of the the auxiliary plot at the position given by 2nd argument. Without this argument the auxiliary plot would be aligned so the its center was aligned at the  position given by 2nd argument.
- The 4th argument gives indicates the scaling to give the auxiliary plot in the $x$ and $y$ directions. In this 40% in both directions.

#### Update

The following is added to address concerns raised by the Rohit Namjoshi in a comment to this answer.

`{Right, Top}` is a simple and convenient form for the 2nd argument of `Inset` to get the inset placed in the upper-right corner, but sometimes you need more control which can be achieved by using `Scaled`. In the case you describe the following appears to work:

```
aux = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π},
  PlotLabel -> "Test", 
  Epilog -> Inset[aux, Scaled[{1, 1}], {Right, Top}, Scaled[{.4, .4}]]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, if I add `PlotLabel -> "Test"` then the inset gets clipped at the top. Looks like `Top` refers to the top of the image, not the top of the frame. Is there a way to align with the frame?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi. I have updated my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Thank you for the update.